# Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Contacts.framework/Contacts?

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Contacts.framework/Contacts
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/3A2851D9-1CA2-47B1-A023-DB324A55B192/OnTrak.app/OnTrak
  Reason: image not found
```

Answer (score 3):

I also got this warning when I run my app on iOS 7 for this answer

1. Select targets
2. build phases

   - Open Link binary with binaries
3. select Contacts.framework and status set to be Optional. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ukt6T.png)

Answer (score 0):

Then it is very simple, you can continue the compatibility as the follow.

float systemVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue];

if (systemVersion < 8.0f) {
//working in ios7 system and above

}else{

//working in ios8 and more

}

Answer (score 0):

O, I find the another way that I can check the runtime whether it have loaded the object. I take the sample about the compatibility between address.framework and contact.framework. we can check using the following.

if (objc_getClass("CNContactStore") == nil) {

}else{

}